# Incluir el nombre de la variable que contiene un arreglo en el JSON a generar

Tags: php, json, array

Pensarán que es una pregunta muy tonta, pero soy novatísimo con PHP y JSON. El inconveniente que no he podido solucionar es el siguiente: Tengo un JSON que extraigo de un arreglo con la orden

```
$json = json_encode($listaUtiles);
print_r($json);
```

El JSON que se muestra es el siguiente:

```
{"Account":"XXXXXXXX","NombreUsuario":"Pedro Pérez","Docto":"5555555","Telefono":"111111","Direccion":"Calle x y-z","Depto":"50","Ciudad":"1","listaUtilesDetalle:":[{"Parte":"xxxxxx","Producto":"Cuaderno 100 hojas","Cantidad":1},{"Parte":"yyyyyyy","Producto":"Lápiz rojo","Cantidad":2}]}
```

Este JSON debo enviarlo a un Web Service , pero el formato que me acepta es el mismo que envío pero anteponiéndole el nombre del array principal, es decir debe ser:

```
[{"listaUtiles:":[{"Account":"XXXXXXXX","NombreUsuario":"Pedro Pérez","Docto":"5555555","Telefono":"111111","Direccion":"Calle x y-z","Depto":"50","Ciudad":"1","listaUtilesDetalle:":[{"Parte":"xxxxxx","Producto":"Cuaderno 100 hojas","Cantidad":1},{"Parte":"yyyyyyy","Producto":"Lápiz rojo","Cantidad":2}]}]}]
```

`$listaUtiles` es el nombre de la variable que contiene el array principal pero este no se muestra cuando genero el JSON. Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan dar.

He intentado con la instrucción `unset` para cambiar el nombre del arreglo pero no me funciona.

```
$array[$listaUtiles] = $array[];
unset($array[]);
```

Comment: $result['listaUtiles']=[$listautiles]; y devuelves json_encode($result);

Comment: Gracias @Jakala ya mejoró el resultado pero sigue sin mostrarme el formato que se pide, me muestra lo siguiente: {"listaUtiles":[{"Account":"XXXXXXXX","NombreUsuario":"Pedro Pérez","Docto":"5555555","Telefono":"111111","Direccion":"Calle x y-z","Depto":"50","Ciudad":"1","listaUtilesDetalle:":[{"Parte":"xxxxxx","Producto":"Cuaderno 100 hojas","Cantidad":1},{"Parte":"yyyyyyy","Producto":"Lápiz rojo","Cantidad":2}]}]} pero no aparece el corchete inicial y el de cierre

Comment: ok. Entonces solo te falta meter el resultado en un array, no? `$result[] = ['listaUtiles' => [$listaUtiles]];` o lo que es lo mismo, tienes un array en el que el pimer elemento es un array asociativo que tiene como clave "listaUtiles" y como datos un array con un array asociativo de datos...

Comment: Excelente @Jakala, muchas gracias.